# Help changing chapter title format

Tags: spacing, formatting, titlesec

I'm trying to use the titlesec package to format chapter and section headings. I had a macro defined that gives me the format that I want, but I can't seem to get the spacing correct when trying to replicate the format with titlesec.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlipsumdefault{1}
\newcommand{\chapterpretitle}{}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\large\scshape\filcenter}{\chapterpretitle}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\newcommand{\ctitle}[2][\*]{%
  \renewcommand{\chapterpretitle}{#1}
  \chapter{#2}}

\newcommand{\ctitleTwo}[2][The Chapter]{
  \begin{center}
    {\scshape\large #1,\\
      called\\
      \Huge\bfseries #2.}
    \end{center}\par}


\begin{document}
\ctitle[The Chapter\\called,]{Chapter One}
\lipsum

\ctitleTwo{Chapter One}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I want the first chapter heading format to match the last one.
This is how it looks to me:

[image: expected outcome]

[image: actual outcome]

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\large\scshape\filcenter}{\chapterpretitle}{-12pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{5pt}

\newcommand{\ctitle}[2][\*]{%
  \renewcommand{\chapterpretitle}{#1}
  \chapter{#2.}}
```